# postgresql Multiple identical conditions are unified into one parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one sql that need convert string column to array and i have to filter with this column，sql like this：

```sql
select
    parent_line,
    string_to_array(parent_line, '-')
from
    bx_crm.department
where
    status = 0 and
    '851' = ANY(string_to_array(parent_line, '-')) and
    array_length(string_to_array(parent_line, '-'), 1) = 5;
```

`parent_line` is a varchar(50) column，the data in this like 0-1-851-88

**question:**

`string_to_array(parent_line, '-')` appear many times in my sql.

1. how many times `string_to_array(parent_line)` calculate in each row. one time or three times
2. how convert `string_to_array(parent_line)` to a parameter. at last,my sql may like this:

```sql
depts = string_to_array(parent_line, '-')

select
    parent_line,
    depts
from
    bx_crm.department
where
    status = 0 and
    '851' = ANY(depts) and
    array_length(depts, 1) = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres supports lateral joins which can simplify this logic:

```
select parent_line, v.parents, status,  ... other columns ...
from bx_crm.department d cross join lateral
     (values (string_to_array(parent_line, '-')) v(parents)
where d.status = 0 and
      cardinality(v.parents) = 5
      '851' = any(v.parents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  select parent_line, 
         string_to_array(parent_line, '-') as parents,
         status, 
         ... other columns ...
  from bx_crm.department
) x
where status = 0
  and cardinality(parents) = 5
  and '851' = any(parents)
```